# "DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path"

Tags: c#

Sorry not so familiar with C#. Why do I get the following error?

```
var workingDirectory = "C:\\Program Files(x86)";

Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(workingDirectory);
```

Error at line `Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(workingDirectory);`

> Throw an exception
>               "DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path"

Comment: copy paste the path in Windows Explorer (File explorer) and see if it can find the path. Also better to check existence of files and folders before using like: `if(Directory.Exists(workingDirectory))... else //handle it`

Answer (score 3):

Do you want the "Special" folder?

```
string WorkingDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)
```

Or actually, do the whole thing in one line:

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86));
```

Comment: A much better and more elegant solution than trying to use magic strings.

Answer (score 0):

There is a space between Files and x86. Try

```
var workingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files (x86)";
```

Comment: I know there is a space but that is the default path found in Windows directory for program files.

Comment: @Yves But your code does not have a space in the path, so the directory cannot be found.